# Does the maximum number of roots in a field directly imply the maximum number of solutions in a group

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory, roots

From Proposition 2.5 from https://wstein.org/edu/2007/spring/ent/ent-html/node28.html#prop:dsols, the maximum number of roots $\alpha\in k$ of $x^n-1$ in a field $k$ is $n$. That is, there are at most $n$ many $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^n-1=0$ in $k$.

I was wondering if it is true, and if so how to prove, that this maximum implies there are at most $n$ solutions to $x^n=1$ in the corresponding multiplicative group $(k\backslash \{0\},\cdot)$.

Logically, I would assume it does, as $0$ cannot be a root of $x^n-1$ in $k$, but I am very new to group theory, and have often found that my logic is wrong.

Thanks :)

Comment: Precisely *what* do you doubt here?  Likely you will get much more helpful answers if you make that clear.

Comment: Assuming known that a quadratic has at most two rational roots can you deduce that it has at most two integer roots, without any such doubts?

Answer (score 1):

As sets, the multiplicative group is a subset of the field. So any solution in the multiplicative group is also a solution in the field. Because the number of solutions in the field is finite, this implies that also the number of solutions in the multiplicative group is finite.