# Is the largest order of an element of a group always the size of the group?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, field-theory

Similar to how one can find a primitive root element of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, I was wondering if, for any group of size $N$ that can be written as $(k\backslash\{0\},\cdot)$ where $k$ is a field, one can find an element of the group such that its order is $N$.

The sketch of my attempted reasoning is as follows:

Lemma 1: Legendre's Theorem says the order of every element of a group divides the size of the group, $N$.

Lemma 2: The order of every element divides the largest order of an element ([Order of any element divides the largest order.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118365/order-of-any-element-divides-the-largest-order)).

Lemma 3: The maximum number of solutions to $x^n=1$ in a group given by $(k\backslash\{0\},\cdot)$, where $k$ is a field, is $n$ (https://wstein.org/edu/2007/spring/ent/ent-html/node28.html#prop:dsols, [Does the maximum number of roots in a field directly imply the maximum number of solutions in a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292178/does-the-maximum-number-of-roots-in-a-field-directly-imply-the-maximum-number-of)).

From Lemma 2 and 3, if the largest order is $n$, then the maximum number of solutions is $n$, but $N$ elements must solve it, so $n\geq N$. From Lemma 1, $n|N$, so $n=N$.

Does this mean that every group that can be defined as $(k\backslash\{0\},\cdot)$, where $k$ is a field, is cyclic??? Or am I missing something? Is there an existing proof of this that has a name?

Comment: For finite fields, yes, it is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response; I am very new to group theory and was wondering if there is a place I can find the formal proof of this online. Thanks. :)